# Who was the first to discover the cosine rule formula?

Tags: trigonometry, soft-question, math-history

A question concerning the cosine rule, every secondary school students uses it. Never I heard teachers explain who discovers it.

My question:

> Who was the first to discover the cosine rule formula?
> $$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(A)$$

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for "history of science and mathematics stackexchange": https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wikipedia says Ghiyāth al-Dīn Jamshīd Masʿūd al-Kāshī in early $1400$s https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines